# Unable to get dictionary value from a list

Tags: python

I have a list like this, i need to get the value of the dictionary for both the keys inside the `dictionary(dict)`

```
dict = [{'module': 'https://svn.domain.com/svn/reponame/branchname', 'revision': 22295}]
```

**expected output :**

https://svn.domain.com/svn/reponame/branchname

22295

Comment: dict is not a dictionary it is a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dict` is actually a dictionary within a list. Try:

```
print(dict[0]['module'])
print(dict[0]['revision'])
```